# Cómo setear el state con un array?

Tags: json, nodejs, reactjs, axios

estoy intentando recuperar información desde el back end mediante axios. La idea es obener el array donde tengo las regiones de mi país, para mas tarde enviarlas a un select, sin embargo no logro setear el array a mi state.

[image: En el primer console.log imprimo la data obtenido con axios para juego hacer setRegiones(res.data.regiones)]

[image: aqui seteo el state]

Answer (score 0):

Estás tratando de incorporar nuevos datos en el "state" de la aplicación. Esto se considera un "side effect" (efecto secundario).

Si estás utilizando componentes funcionales (en vez de componentes Clase), los efectos secundarios deben realizarse dentro de él hook [`useEffect`](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect):

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";


const obtenerRegiones = async () => {
  try {
    return await axios.get("https://some-api-url.com/regions");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

function App() {
  const [regions, setRegions] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    obtenerRegiones()
      .then(results => setRegions(results))
  }, []);

  return <div>{JSON.stringify(regions)}</div>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: muchas gracias colega !